# I am trying to add my checkbox item to the state array and remove them once unchecked - React useState

Tags: reactjs

I was trying one of my previous code to add checkbox data to state but the problem

1. The checkbox never get checked
2. every time the checkbox is clicked creates a repeated item
3. doesn't remove the item from the state if unchecked

```js
 const [target_user, SetTarget_user] = useState([]);
 const OnAddSelect = e => {
    const fieldname = e.target.name;
    // [...old] to create a new array out of the previous values. Protects against mutation
    const options = target_user; // Access object as an array for computed property name

    if (e.target.checked) {
      options.push({[fieldname]:e.target.value, status:"TODO"});
    } else {
      let index = options.indexOf({[fieldname]:e.target.value});
      options.splice(index, 1);
    }
    // use same computed property name as above
    SetTarget_user([
      ...target_user], {[fieldname]: options}
    )
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onChange={OnAddSelect} name="target_user" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" onChange={OnAddSelect} name="target_user" value="c">
<input type="checkbox" onChange={OnAddSelect} name="target_user" value="d">
<input type="checkbox" onChange={OnAddSelect} name="target_user" value="e">
```

It would be great if someone can explain where I am making a wrong and better way to fix.

Comment: I'm not sure if your `SetTarget_user` method works. Have you tried changing it from the capital 'S' to lowercase 's'?

Comment: Should give different names to the checkboxes?